# Open Covers for Čech Homology

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

Would it make sense to define a filtered open covering 
$$\{U_i\} = U_1 < U_2 < \cdots < U_n = X$$ on a topological space $X$ in order to compute Čech homology? Or does this defeat the purpose?

Context: I have a cosheaf $F$ on a space $X$ in which the stalk is only non trivial for a set of points lying on a vertical line. The only way to define an open covering in which most of the intersections are non-zero is to take the filtered covering described. The aim is to compute Čech homology with coefficents in $F$ given that open covering of $X$.

Comment: Have you tried to see what the Cech complex looks like in that case?

Comment: In any case, such open coverings very, very rarely are cofinal in the set of all coverings, so it is not clear what you mean when you say you want to take such a covering to compute Cech homology.

Comment: Basically, I have a cosheaf F on a space X in which the stalk is only non trivial for a set of points lying on a vertical line. The only way to define an open covering in which most of the intersections are non-zero is to take the filtered covering described. The aim is to compute cech homology with coefficents in F given that open covering of X.

Comment: @user84563 Can you include that in your question, i.e., add as much context as possible?

Comment: Why are you updating many questions from long ago? That pushes them to the top of the active question queue and distracts people from new postings that really warrant attention?